# How To STOP VBA Interpreting an Integer function arguments as boolean if the integer is 0 or -1

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion, integer, boolean

**Please look at my code I posted after this. It isolates the problem more succinctly.**

I am trying to trap an argument error, i.e. if Excel user puts a boolean in for `intTestVar` which should be an integer. VBA interprets a 0 or -1 entry (which is legal) as a boolean. If user enters a boolean (illegal) it interprets it as an integer, i.e -1 or 0. I understand that if you cast a boolean as an integer it will be -1 or 0 but I am not casting it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function TestA(filler As Integer, Optional intTestVar As Integer = 0) As Integer
    Dim intTrap As Integer
    intTrap = 0
     
    On Error GoTo ErrorH
    
    Debug.Print "how VBA sees the argument variable " & intTestVar & " type = " & VarType(intTestVar)
    
    If VarType(intTestVar) = vbBoolean Then
        intTrap = 1
        GoTo ErrorH
    End If
    
    'in case that doesn't work
    If intTestVar = False Or intTestVar = True Then
        intTrap = 2
        GoTo ErrorH
    End If
             
    'in case that doesn't work
    If IsNumeric(intTestVar) = False Then
        intTrap = 3
        GoTo ErrorH
    End If
    
    TestA = 10 * intTestVar
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrorH:
    Debug.Print intTrap & " Trapped the Bugger "
    Resume Next
End Function
```

This is how it responded to different values for `intTestVar` - filler is just a dummy = 5

```
Entering 6 return 60
how VBA sees the argument variable 6 type = 2

Entering -1 returned 0
how VBA sees the argument variable -1 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
2 Trapped the Bugger 

Entering True Returned 0
how VBA sees the argument variable -1 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
2 Trapped the Bugger 

Entering False Returned 0
how VBA sees the argument variable 0 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
2 Trapped the Bugger
```

As a side, I don't know why the error handler repeats the error message, resume next should clear the error...??

Comment: I think your problem is that VBA has perform the `CInt()` cast before your function runs - you cannot "reach back" to see what was actually passed.  If you wanted to do that then maybe declare `Optional intTestVar As Variant = 0`

Answer (score 0):

## Consider this:

This is your same code, but I added some `Debug.Print` statements and a test routine:

```
Public Function TestA(filler As Integer, Optional intTestVar As Integer = 0) As Integer
Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------------------------"
Dim intTrap As Integer
intTrap = 0
 
On Error GoTo ErrorH

Debug.Print "how VBA sees the argument variable " & intTestVar & " type = " & VarType(intTestVar)

If VarType(intTestVar) = vbBoolean Then
    intTrap = 1
    GoTo ErrorH
End If

'in case that doesn't work
If intTestVar = False Or intTestVar = True Then
    intTrap = 2
    GoTo ErrorH
End If

         
'in case that doesn't work
If IsNumeric(intTestVar) = False Then
    intTrap = 3
    GoTo ErrorH
End If


TestA = 10 * intTestVar

Exit Function

ErrorH:
Debug.Print intTrap & " Trapped the Bugger "
Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
Resume Next

End Function

'-----------------------------------------
Sub test()

Debug.Print TestA(5, -1)
Debug.Print TestA(5, 5)
Debug.Print TestA(5, True)
Debug.Print TestA(5, False)

End Sub
```

#### Output of test():

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
how VBA sees the argument variable -1 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
0       
2 Trapped the Bugger 
20      Resume without error
 0 
------------------------------------------------------------------
how VBA sees the argument variable 5 type = 2
 50 
------------------------------------------------------------------
how VBA sees the argument variable -1 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
0       
2 Trapped the Bugger 
20      Resume without error
 0 
------------------------------------------------------------------
how VBA sees the argument variable 0 type = 2
2 Trapped the Bugger 
0       
2 Trapped the Bugger 
20      Resume without error
 0
```

## Thoughts

So... you're getting the repeating error routine because you don't actually have an error when you hit that `resume next`.  You got there in the first place just because you used `GoTo ErrorH` to force it there, but no error.

As for the boolean trapping... I'm not seeing an issue there, because it seems that `True` and `False` return -1 and 0 respectively, and they are recognized as variable type 2 (integer).  I guess I don't quite see your problem and perhaps you can clarify it if this doesn't answer it.

Comment: Yes. `True` and `False` are numeric -1 and 0, respectively. There is no problem, it is by design.

Comment: It is pointless to pass `intTestVar As Integer` to either `VarType` or `IsNumeric`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TestA(filler As Integer, Optional intTestVar As Integer = 0) As Integer

'This test function demonstrates a VBA bug. It is interpreting the declared integers 0 and -1 as boolean
'in some expressions but not all expressions involving a boolean related test.

Dim intTrap As Integer
intTrap = 0
 
TestA = 999

Debug.Print "This is how VBA sees the integer argument: inTestVar = " & intTestVar & " type = " & VarType(intTestVar)

On Error GoTo ErrorH


If VarType(intTestVar) = vbBoolean Then
    intTrap = 1
    GoTo ErrorH
End If


'this is the problem statement. The If test should be False but VBA interprets as True
If intTestVar = False Or intTestVar = True Then
    intTrap = 2
    GoTo ErrorH
End If


TestA = 10 * intTestVar
Debug.Print "TestA returns: " & TestA
Debug.Print " "
Debug.Print " "

Exit Function


ErrorH:
Debug.Print "Trap " & intTrap & " Trapped Error: inTestvar treated as boolean " & " TESTA Returns " & TestA
Debug.Print " "
Debug.Print " "


End Function



*I entered 8 and then -1 for the argument intTestVar with these results.*

This is how VBA sees the integer argument: inTestVar = 8 type = 2
TestA returns: 80
 
 
This is how VBA sees the integer argument: inTestVar = -1 type = 2
Trap 2 Trapped Error: inTestvar treated as boolean  TESTA Returns 999
```

Comment: Well my workaround didn't work - got confused along the way.  But it all comes down to this. In VBA 10 * TRUE = -10 and 10 * FALSE = 0.  There is no way to distinguish between a boolean providence for a variable and an integer providence. If you trap a boolean entry in the integer argument you also trap the integers -1 and 0;   If you allow the -1 and 0 you allow the boolean.   A serious bug in VBA IMO.

Comment: I finally got a solution that works.  Declared the argument variable as Variant.  Then converted it to a string, Then I did a conditional comparison to "False" and "True", if It matched either then I raise an error and the boolean entry is trapped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This makes no sense. `intTestVar` is declared `As Integer`, it is never a boolean. You can pass a `True` or `False` into it, and you cannot stop people from doing that. It is documented that True is then converted to -1 and False to 0. This happens [before `TestA` is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615227/how-to-stop-vba-interpreting-an-integer-function-arguments-as-boolean-if-the-int#comment124831405_70615227), so from inside of `TestA` it is impossible to tell whether the calling code gave you a True or a -1, unless you declare the argument as `Variant`.